# java run only one instance at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail

I am using Java(Servlet,JSP) to develop a web application.

I have a class which send emails.

Class looks like:

```
public class EmailSender
{
    String SendEmail(String from,Session session,String To,String CC, String BCC, String Subject,String Body)
    {
        //Actual code for sending emails
    }
}
```

`EmailSender` class is called from another class:

```
public class InvokeSender
{
    public InvokeSender(String dbFileName)
    {
        //get emails from database for sending who has STATUS='NOTSENT'
        //statements to get all required parameter to pass to SendEmail()
        EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();
        String msg = sender.SendEmail(fromEmail,session,To,CC,BCC,SUBJECT,BODY);
    }
}
```

And `InvokeSender` is called from servlet when the used clicks the button.

When user clicks on button the InvokeSender is called, which takes emails to be send from database and forms them and then pass those parameters to `SendEmail()` of `EmailSender` class.

I want only one instance of `InvokeSender` to run at a time to avoid same emails going twice if the button is pressed twice. How this can be handled? Will `multithreading` useful in this case?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update1**
I can't disable the button after user clicks it. Because if user refresh the page then that button will be enabled by default.

**Update2**
First user selects customers, template etc. for sending emails and after that email parameters are stored in database. `InvokeSender` class get all emails to be sent. Number of emails to be sent can't be predicted. It can be 1 or 500 or more than that. I want only one instance of `InvokeSender` to run until previous instance is completed sending emails. Functionality (Button to generate and send email) will be exposed to 5-7 users.

Comment: What about simply disabling the button after the user clicks it?

Comment: Disabling the button is a good idea, however I think the intent is to build a robust server component that has no dependency on the UI.  For example, one may want to expose this functionality via a web service interface.

Comment: @Joe Please see `update1`

Comment: how about making an ajax call(to send the email and store email sent against the user in a table) and disable the button. on page loading, check if email is not sent and enable the button?

Comment: @Bhushan If the user has sent a mail, till how much more time to do you wish to not send him the next mail. implementation will depend on that.

Comment: @Jatin Please see `update2`

Comment: what about adding CAPTCHA code

Comment: Disabling button is good. Do you have any intervals between mails.

Comment: @KanagarajM No there are no intervals between emails. Interface for sending emails will be provided to at least 5-7 users so I think disabling the button of one user can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

I think, can done by creating a unique token with session scoped for the page whichever has email sender and a Singleton Map in the Servlet class to maintain the token.

1. Create a servlet filter to generate a session scoped token for page.
2. if token does not exists in the Map, then add the token into the
       Map and invoke mail sender.
3. If contains, then don’t invoke mail
       sender

Answer (score 1):

You can use a queue datastructure to queue the send-email requests and process the same in a separate thread. This thread will be spawned once during startup and will process the queue. When the email is sent the `STATUS='NOTSENT'` will be cleared, this will solve the multiple email problems. The queue can be processed at regular intervals or can be polled for data or have some signalling mechanism to signal the thread when there is data in the queue.

**Edit:** I think this solution caters to **Update1** and **Update2**

Answer (score 1):

I would use an AtomicBoolean in InvokeSender then do this:

```
public class InvokeSender
{
  static AtomicBoolean sendInProgress = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public InvokeSender(String dbFileName)
  {
    if (sendInProgress.compareAndSet(false, true)) {

      //get emails from database for sending who has STATUS='NOTSENT'
      //statements to get all required parameter to pass to SendEmail()
      EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();
      String msg = sender.SendEmail(fromEmail,session,To,CC,BCC,SUBJECT,BODY);

      sendInProgress.set(false); 
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this is a very simple solution, if you want more complex behavior like limiting the time between the previous email and the next, you would have to add a bit more logic to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use synchornized block

```
        public InvokeSender(String dbFileName)
        {
           synchronized(InvokeSender.class){ 
           //get emails from database for sending who has STATUS='NOTSENT'
            //statements to get all required parameter to pass to SendEmail()
            EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();
            String msg = sender.SendEmail(fromEmail,session,To,CC,BCC,SUBJECT,BODY);
          }
        }
```